# On quasi-modular forms with integer Fourier coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms

It is well-known that the ring $M$ of modular forms has the structure $M=\mathbb{C}[E_4,E_6]$, where $E_k$ are the Eisenstein series.

It is also known that one can define the concept of quasi-modular forms so that the ring $\hat M$ of quasi-modular forms is given analogously by $\hat M=\mathbb{C}[E_2,E_4,E_6]$.
We note that both $M$ and $\hat M$ can be thought of as subrings of $\mathbb{C}[[q]]$ by taking the Fourier expansion.

Now, Zagier states matter-of-factory in his “Note on the Landweber-Stong elliptic genus” ([available from his own webpage from here](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/BFb0078047/fulltext.pdf)) that the mod-$p$ reduction of $M \cap \mathbb{Z}[[q]]$ and $\hat M\cap \mathbb{Z}[[q]]$ agree for all prime $p$, see the first line of p.222 there.

Where can the proof of this statement be found?

Comment: This follows from Fermat's little theorem (and Clausen-von Staudt): $E_2\equiv E_{p+1}\pmod{p}$.

Comment: Why does it help? From $E_2 \equiv E_{p+1}$ mod $p$ I can show $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} [[E_2,E_4,E_6]]=\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} [[E_4,E_6]]$ and therefore  $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} [[E_2,E_4,E_6]]\cap \mathbb{Z}[[q]]=\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} [[E_4,E_6]]\cap \mathbb{Z}[[q]]$, but I don't think it tells us much about $\mathbb{C} [[E_2,E_4,E_6]]\cap \mathbb{Z}[[q]]$...